# Multiple cancel links do not redirect properly in drupal

Tags: drupal, recurring-billing

If a user clicks the "update" link in their recurring fees table, then decides not to make any changes and clicks Cancel instead of Update, they get access denied because the cancel link redirects to the admin view of recurring fees, not back to the user view. This is with the authorize.net handler, the URL in question is like the following:

example.com/user/263/recurring/715/cancel/authorizenet_cim?destination=user/263/recurring-fees

This is the code I got when I am doing research, I changed my code according to the mentioned below,but it does't work for me any help!

In uc_recurring.uc_authorizenet.inc around lines 140-147:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Update'),
// '#suffix' => l(t('Cancel'), 'admin/store/orders/recurring/view/fee/' . $rfid),
'#suffix' => l(t('Cancel'), $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), //This is the line I have added 
);
```

Comment: Bugs with Drupal modules need to go in the relevant [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/uc_recurring?categories=bug) they aren't on-topic here (nor on the Drupal Answers website). You haven't mentioned _what_ module you're using so I've taken a guess at UC recurring for that link.

Comment: Yes! your correct, uc_recurring.module takes care of this.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy, you can add the Rules, it will redirect.